# Three-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

In a classification problem, I have `c` classes of data, each with `e` examples of this data, and each example is represented by a feature vector of length `f`. What's the best way to represent this structure in Matlab?

I could use a `c-by-e` cell array, where each element is 1D array of length `f`. However, I would like to avoid using cell arrays. If I use a 3D array, I'm not sure how to implement this. What would be the dimensions? `(c, e, f)` or `(f, e, c)`?

Comment: `(c, e, f) or (f, e, c)?` - It doesn't matter as long as you know how to use(index) it correctly later on. Also, keeping `c by e` pattern would be useful I think. Thus, `(c, e, f)` would be preferred over `(f, e, c)` to keep it intuitive.

Comment: Do you usually chose an answer to your questions? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's best to place the longest vector in a column. Therefore, `(f, e, c)` should be better than `(c, e, f)`, assuming that `f` is indeed the longest dimension.

MATLAB is most efficient when working in columns, and many built-in functions are coded to work columnwise by default.

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/using-columnwise-processing-to-speed-up-sliding-neighborhood-or-distinct-block-operations.html.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction with a 3D matrix is that dimensions must have a fixed length (so all classes would have to have the same number of examples, and features).

Assuming that you want a general answer, and providing you want to avoid cell arrays, you could use a structure array:

```
c(3).name = 'cls3';  %// name of 3rd class

c(3).example(1).name = 'c3e1';    %// name of 1st example of 3rd class 
c(3).example(1).data = [1 2 3 4];  %// not sure what is your data structure here
c(3).example(1).features_ID = [101 102];  %// ID of features

c(3).example(2).name = 'c3e2';
c(3).example(2).data = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
c(3).example(2).features_ID = [101 102 103];
```

I only filled in the 3rd class, with 2 examples, but you get the idea.